# Convergence of matrix multiplication sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence

I am an engineer whose job involves system identification. When dealing with state-space models, I have to inspect the convergence of some matrix multiplication sequence.
I understand the case in which A is a square matrix and all of the eigenvalues of A are bound by [-1,1]: 
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} A^k = 0 $$
However, if A is now variable: $$ A_k = B + L \cdot x_k $$
($B$ and $L$ are constant matrices while $x_k$ is a variable vector) then the multipication sequence becomes:
$$ P_k = \prod_{i=1}^{i=k} A_i $$

My question is whether there is any condition on the series {$x_k$} as well as the matrices $B$ and $L$ (or simply on $ A_k$) so that:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} P_k = 0 $$
Thank you very much!